# MapStruct: Object.class to Custom.class mapping

Tags: java, object-object-mapping, mapstruct

I'm a newbie with **MapStruct**, and need some help with that.

I have a Source class, with an attribute

```
Object input;
```

Which, in runtime, returns a custom object named TicketDetails.

Now, in my target class there is a attribute named,

```
MyTicket myTicket;
```

which, I need to map with an attribute of TicketDetails object.
For, better understanding, I'm writing the normal java code example below.

```
SourceClassModel sourceClassModel = new SourceClassModel();
TargetClassModel targetClassModel = new TargetClassModel();

//mapping
TicketDetails ticketDetails = (TicketDetails) sourceClassModel.getInput();
targetClassModel.setMyTicket(ticketDetails.getMyTicket);
```

Now, my question is, how to achieve this case using **MapStruct**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either on a used mapper (see `@Mapper#uses()`) or in a non-abstract method on the mapper itself - in case it is an abstract class and not an interface - define the mapping from `Object` to `TicketDetails` yourself:

```
TicketDetails asTicketDetails(Object details) {
    return (TicketDetails) details;
}
```

The generated method for the conversion of `SourceClassModel` to `TargetClassModel` will then invoke that manually written method for converting the `myTicket` property.