# Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring-mvc, mapstruct

I'm trying to my map local pojo to an autogenerated domain objects using mapstruct. Expect for a specific complex structure everything else seems to map and the mapper implementation class gets generation. Below is the error that I get.

My mapper class is:

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "sourcefile", target = "sourceFILE"),
        @Mapping(source = "id", target = "ID"),
        @Mapping(source = "reg", target = "regID"),
        @Mapping(source = "itemDetailsType", target = "ItemDetailsType") //This is the structure that does not map
})
AutoGenDomainType map(LocalPojo localPojo);

@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "line", target = "LINE"),
        @Mapping(source = type", target = "TYPE")
})
ItemDetailsType map(ItemDetailsTypes itemDetailsType);
```

Error:

```
Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException         at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.hasCompatibleCopyConstructor(MappingResolverImpl.java:547)          at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.isPropertyMappable(MappingResolverImpl.java:522)   at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.getTargetAssignment(MappingResolverImpl.java:202)   at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.access$100(MappingResolverImpl.java:153)    at  org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl.getTargetAssignment(MappingResolverImpl.java:121)   at 
.....
.....
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Found 1 error and 16 warnings.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project uwo-services: Compilation failure
```

The target object `ItemDetailsType` does have other properties that need not be mapped. The error says compilation issue, but I dont find any. Also I have tried adding have tried the `unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE` at my mapper class level just to avoid if this is caused by the unmapped properties, but still no solution.

Comment: Found the answer for a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994644/mapstruct-object-class-to-custom-class-mapping

Comment: @KarthikeyanKesavaraj I did check that. It explains how to use mapStruct to map a complex object that are structurally different. However in my case I have other properties that gets mapped and one that doesn't. It throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in MapStruct. The bug is reported in [#729](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/729), it has been fixed in 1.1.0.Final. You are using 1.0.0.Final. I would highly suggest switching to the either 1.1.0.Final or 1.2.0.Beta2.

Once you update you will see a better error message and you will know exactly what the problem in the mapping is.

By looking at this first it looks like that target in `@Mapping(source = "itemDetailsType", target = "ItemDetailsType")` is wrong. Are you sure that you need a capital letter there?

Comment: You are right I'm using 1.0.0 Final and changing version to 1.1.0 did not give me any error message but actually generated the class that I wanted. However I cannot commit the changes with the new version. So I did a work around by using using `@AfterMapping` and set my values.